# Logon to Crystal Report server fails using Java SDK due to NoClassDefFound error from bcm.jar in AWS Fargate Container

Tags: java, crystal-reports, amazon-ecs

I am using Crystal Report product to generate PDF reports. Earlier I was using a lower version of server. Now I upgraded the server to a latest version. I got the corresponding Java Crystal Report SDK client libraries. In AWS Pipeline I am able to download those jars from repo. Seems like our spring boot fat jar packaged has all the required jars except bcm.jar. After app build I don't face any challenge to publish to artifactory and deploy into AWS ECS Container. App starts fine, healthcheck and all other APIs behaves normally. I are able to invoke the rest apis which generate the crystal report using postman. It is failing during sessionMgr.logon in following snippets of code

```
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.CrystalEnterprise;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.IEnterpriseSession;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.ISessionMgr;

ISessionMgr sessionMgr = CrystalEnterprise.getSessionMgr();
IEnterpriseSession enterpriseSession = sessionMgr.logon(userId, password, serverName, rasAuthType);
```

I am getting following runtime exception during the logon phase. I am catching Throwable in that manner I am able to understand the same

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.businessobjects.bcm.BCM
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.ConfidentialChannelService.establishConfidentialChannel(ConfidentialChannelService.java:189) ~[cecore-14.3.0.jar!/:14.2.9.4130]
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.ConfidentialChannelService.createConfidentialChannel(ConfidentialChannelService.java:149) ~[cecore-14.3.0.jar!/:14.2.9.4130]
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.CCMap.locateCCItem(CCMap.java:63) ~[cecore-14.3.0.jar!/:14.2.9.4130]
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.LogonService.doUserLogon(LogonService.java:938) ~[cecore-14.3.0.jar!/:14.2.9.4130]
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.LogonService.doUserLogon(LogonService.java:892) ~[cecore-14.3.0.jar!/:14.2.9.4130]
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.LogonService.userLogon(LogonService.java:248) ~[cecore-14.3.0.jar!/:14.2.9.4130]
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.SecurityMgr.userLogon(SecurityMgr.java:166) ~[cecore-14.3.0.jar!/:14.2.9.4130]
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.internal.SessionMgr.logon_aroundBody0(SessionMgr.java:823) ~[cesession-14.3.0.jar!/:14.2.9.4130]
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.internal.SessionMgr.logon_aroundBody1$advice(SessionMgr.java:523) ~[cesession-14.3.0.jar!/:14.2.9.4130]
at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.internal.SessionMgr.logon(SessionMgr.java:1) ~[cesession-14.3.0.jar!/:14.2.9.4130]
```

Following are the old and new versions of crystal report jars

[image: Following are the old and new versions of crystal repjars]

Comment: Does it work when you run the same docker image locally?

Comment: I don't have docker locally. I can't try that in my local. Buy when I set up the code locally and run in sts it works perfectly fine. I am able to connect to crystal report server and generate the report.

Comment: Running the code locally without Docker doesn't test how you are building the Docker image. You need to be able to verify the image outside of AWS to determine if there is an issue with the AWS configuration, or an issue with the Docker image. There really isn't any AWS configuration issue that would cause the error you are getting, so it really looks like an issue with the Docker image.

Comment: May be you are correct. But currently I am not getting any Docker set up. I will be trying the same if I get Docker set up. But as pointed in the screenshot Crystal Report has multiple jars and on top of it I have other jars as well. All other Crystal Report jars are loaded. Only bcm jar is unavailable at run time as it throws Runtime exception. I am suspecting the way bcm.jar is build it has some issue. If I get some person who worked on Crystal Report jars and integrated bcm.jar recently that will help me. If someone is from SAP the crystal report product that can also help.

Comment: As far as your AWS deployment is concerned, the jars are just files inside the docker image. If they aren't correct, it is not an AWS problem. If you want support from SAP I'm sure you will have to pay for that, and you would need to reach out to SAP for that, I don't think they provide free support on this website.

Comment: I am going to try that route also. But if know someone who can help please help me to engage him. I think many people use Crystal Report till now. Because it is one of the widely use PDF Report Generation tool.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257100/discussion-between-dipak-dutta-and-mark-b).

Answer (score 0):

I deployed the application in IBM WebSphere Portal. There I am able to deploy the application successfully without any issues during build or deployment. Later I am able to logon to Crystal Report Server successfully and generate the PDF reports. I am looking into what is the issue happening with the docker image when I am deploying the same in AWS ECS Container. @Mark B